# How to pass the value of span in html to other page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to pass the value of my span html which is the value, is from the javascript. It will count the words of the uploaded file. please help me guys for this.

Heres my first page **index.php**

```
<form name="myform" action="values.php" method="post">
   <input name="upload" type="file" id="upload" accept="text/plain" accesskey="u"> UPLOAD A FILE
   <span id="display_File_count" name="display_File_count"></span> <span>Words</span>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#upload').change( function(event) {

        var f = event.target.files[0];
        if (f) {
            var r = new FileReader();

            r.onload = function(e) { 
                var contents = e.target.result;
                var res = contents.split(" "); 
                $("#display_File_count").text(res.length);
            }
            r.readAsText(f);
        }
    });

</script>
```

And heres the other page that will call the value **values.php**

```
<input type="text" name="count_upload" id="count_upload" value="<?php echo $_POST["display_File_count"] ?>" >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an hidden input that will contain the file count (updated from js) and submit button to send data to the other page :

```
<form name="myform" action="values.php" method="post">
    <input name="upload" type="file" id="upload" accept="text/plain" accesskey="u">
    UPLOAD A FILE

    <span id="display_File_count" name="display_File_count"></span><span>Words</span>

     <input type="hidden" name="display_File_count" class='display_File_count' />

     <input type='submit' value='send data to the other page' />
</form>
```

To update field from js you could use :

```
...
r.onload = function(e) { 
    var contents = e.target.result;
    var res = contents.split(" "); 
    $("#display_File_count").text(res.length);

    $(".display_File_count").val(res.length);
}
...
```

When you click on submit button the parameter `display_File_count` will be send automatically to `values.php` with method `post`, so you should find in `values.php` the input filled automatically by `display_File_count` since you're using `$_POST["display_File_count"]` in the other side.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hello, the value of span is the number of words from the uploaded file which is counted by javascript to i want to get the value(count of words) to the other page ^^.

Comment: Why you're not using form? then you can submit with action to the other page.

Comment: i forgot to put the form sir, but i use form `<form name="myform" action="values.php" method="post">`

Comment: so how will i call it to the other page sir?

Comment: When you click on submit button the parameter `display_File_count` will be send automatically to `values.php` with method `post`, so you should find in `values.php` the input filled automatically by `display_File_count` since you're using `$_POST["display_File_count"]` in the other side.

Comment: i've use it sir but it's still not get the value from the other page T__T

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104345/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-loucelle-emperio).