# How to pass a span value VUE

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, vue.js

I have forms

```
<input type="text" v-model="email">
<span>Value</span>
```

How to pass a span value to?

```
data () {
    return {
    email: '/*Here is value span*/'
}
}
```

Comment: Actuallly what you want to do? Can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: recommend read https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass the value of span in html to other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589949/how-to-pass-the-value-of-span-in-html-to-other-page)

Comment: it seems `<span>{{email}}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the input such as 'emailID'

Then use -

```
var email = document.getElementById('emailID').value;
```

Then use -

```
data () {
    return {
    'email:' + email
    }
}
```

Or with ES6

```
data () {
    return {
    (`email: ${email}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: And if I just need to use v-model